# How can I :vs between two tabs in vim

Tags: vim

I know how to open up separate tabes (`:tabe ../otherfile`)

I know how to compare two files (`:vs ../otherfile`)

Lets say I have two tabs already open, is there a way to compare the two active tabs the same way `:vs` works? It would be the equivilient to telling vim "run `:vs` on the other active tab"

More so, is there a way I can search with `tabe` for a file to compare to my original? Psudo command would be to run `:vs :tabe`, the second file that is compared to the first should be the one I find while searching with tabexplorer.

Comment: Well tabs in vim are used for example to have different window layouts on one or multiple buffers.
So the idea would be to have a tab that is used to have files (buffers) open in split mode and maybe another tab to just have one window/view on one particular buffer.
If you have one tab with a view on buffer A.txt and another tab that simply has a view on B.txt that is not really how tabs are meant to be used in vim. You would rather use one tab to have a single view on one file/buffer (either A or B) and the other tab could be used to have a split (A|B).